# How to fix search query using LIKE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, string

I'm new to database programming and I'm trying to search the database for strings using LIKE.

When I search for Fiction the Non-Fiction books also come up.
What Can I do to show only Fiction rows if the keyword is Fiction?

Note: I must be allowed not only to search for fiction and non-fiction but also to search for ISBN, Book title from the text box.

Comment: Is your problem the SQL or is it the c# code? If it is the c#, how do you connect to the database, do you use the entity framework?

Comment: Very confusing question. Do you getting in SQL query or c# code?

Comment: I think my problem is in the SQL query. Is there anyway to limit the search for the Fiction keyword so if you search by that keyword it would not include the Non-Fiction books? since Fiction is in the "Non-Fiction" string.

Comment: Yes, there is, assuming that you have some categories or genres in the database, you can filter by genre and say something like `SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Genre NOT LIKE 'Fiction'`. But in order to make it the way that you have described, then you need some logic in the c# application and in the SQL query, so that it will know when it has to search for ISBN and when for something else.

Comment: Without information about your table structures etc unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are confuse that how to use LIKE query , Please check following examples:

```
1 - SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookname LIKE 's%'; [It will return all books which starts from letter "S" in bookname]

2 - SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookname LIKE '%s'; [It will return all books which ending with letter "S" in bookname]

3 - SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookname LIKE '%Fiction%'; [It will return all books which contains letters "Fiction" in bookname]

4 - SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookname NOT LIKE '%Non%'; [It will return all books which not containing "Non" in bookname]
```

You please change you appropiate field name and table name.

Hope above will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link.It will help you to get more knowledge about **LIKE** statement.

[Use of LIKE query using SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php)

For search bookname starts with "Fiction" you have to use query as below mentioned.

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookname LIKE 'Fiction%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do something with an inclusion and exlusion:

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookName LIKE 'Fiction%' and BookName NOT LIKE '%Non-Fiction%'
```

From what you saying about the text box, where the text input can be representative of any of the fields, assuming that you pass a parameter you should be able to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Books 
WHERE BookName LIKE '%' + @Input + '%'
OR ISBN LIKE '%' + @Input + '%' 
OR BookType LIKE '%' + @Input + '%' OR etc...
```

Obviously though, this will get you a book named "Strange Fiction" if you are simply using the same search box to look for books that are "Fiction".  You may want to consider multiple search boxes in that case.